# JavaFX 8 Bindings.when and Bindings.divide creates Divide by zero

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm struggling with Bindings.when... I'm attempting to create a percentage score that updates when either the number of successful tests changes (reflected in the code below as 'successCountProperty'), or the total number of tests changes (reflected in the sizeProperty of 'results'). When I execute this code, I get java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero. When I initially encountered the exception, I found Bindings.when().then().otherwise(), which in my head should solve the problem. Unfortunately, upon executing this code, the 'then' is executing despite the 'when' returning false. Can anyone help?

```
public void foo()
{
    DoubleProperty scoreProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    ListProperty<String> results = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    IntegerProperty successCountProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    scoreProperty.bind(Bindings.when(results.sizeProperty().greaterThan(0))
            .then(Bindings.divide(successCountProperty, results.sizeProperty())).otherwise(0));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More complex bindings using the methods of `Bindings` or the property itself can easily become confusing to read and difficult to maintain.

In this case I recommend creating a `DoubleBinding` with a custom evaluation method:

```
scoreProperty.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    int size = results.size();
    return size == 0 ? 0d : ((double) successCountProperty.get()) / size;
}, results.sizeProperty(), successCountProperty));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
Bindings.divide(successCountProperty, results.sizeProperty())
```

is evaluated immediately and you seem to be expecting [lazy evaluation](http://confluence.gfinet.com/display/ECREDIT/Environments#STGEnvironments-816889316).

You could write your own lazy divider which only does the division when the value is actually queried:

```
class LazyDivision extends DoubleBinding
{
    private IntegerProperty dividend;
    private ReadOnlyIntegerProperty divisor;

    LazyDivision(final IntegerProperty dividend, final ReadOnlyIntegerProperty divisor)
    {
        this.dividend = dividend;
        this.divisor = divisor;
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeValue()
    {
        return dividend.getValue() / divisor.getValue().doubleValue();
    }
}
```

and then use that like so:

```
scoreProperty.bind(
    Bindings
        .when(results.sizeProperty().greaterThan(0))
        .then(
            new LazyDivision(successCountProperty, results.sizeProperty())
        )
        .otherwise(0)
);
```

Comment: This code never adds a listener to `successCountProperty`. If only this value is modified the bound property will not be updated. This is most certainly not the desired effect.